# How to change the selected text color in a TextBlock in a ListView?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

I am building a Windows 8 store application and I can't manage to change the highlighted/selected color a of TextBlock in a ListView.

Here's how I create my ListView :

```
<ListView x:Name="zonesList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="516" Margin="50,175,0,0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LocalizationCellSample}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="355" DataContext="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="zonesList_SelectionChanged"/>
```

And my data binding:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="LocalizationCellSample">
  <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ListBoxTextStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="200" MaxHeight="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,5,0,0" FontFamily="Global User Interface"/>
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

What's the easiest way?

EDIT:

Here's the ListBoxTextStyle

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxTextStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
  <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Light" />
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Can you post the style for `ListBoxTextStyle`?

Comment: Do you want to change the TextColor of the TextBlock or the color of the ListBox for highlighting the selected item?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I added the ListBoxTextStyle in my post.

Comment: @Jehof Actually, I would like to change both. :)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Add ItemContainerStyle to the ListView]

Add the `ItemContainerStyle` like the picture shows in the "DocumentOutline" Panel in Visual Studio. Then Edit the `VisualState` as below:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Selected">
    <Storyboard>
        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="Red" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ContentPresenter.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter" />
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
<VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
    <Storyboard>
        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="Red" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ContentPresenter.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter" />
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Usually, the `"contentPresenter"` is added to the `ItemContainerStyle` by default. The `Foreground` of the `"contentPresenter"` changes, the Color of Text will change.

As for the `Background` of the selected `ListViewItem`, nearly the same as above.

By the way, It works in `WP8.1`, at least. And if you do it in `Blend`, it will be  easier.

Answer (score 0):

You could try by adding this to your standardstyles.xaml file in your Common folder:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#009ACD"></SolidColorBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#CCC"></SolidColorBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#00688B"></SolidColorBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush" Color="Black" Opacity="0"></SolidColorBrush>
```

inside your resourcedictionary tags

So it would look somthing like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#009ACD"></SolidColorBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#CCC"></SolidColorBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#00688B"></SolidColorBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush" Color="Black" Opacity="0"></SolidColorBrush>


    </ResourceDictionary>


</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```

This way all the items in your listview will get a certain color when they are selected etc

Comment: It works for the background color cell, thanks. However I still can't manage to edit the selected text color when the cell is selected. Any ideas? ;)

Comment: @AntoineGamond I dont know your code exaclty but maybe you could use a Color property that you bind to your textBox 'Foreground="{Binding $$$$}" ' and then change the color of the property with something like var Blue = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.RoyalBlue); when you need it to(in your case when the item is selected). I hope this is a bit clear :)

Comment: I thought about that but I think it's not a good way to do this. This should be automatic, not manually activated.

Comment: @AntoineGamond well maybe this will work then, not sure though havent used this myself, just a quick thought <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush" Color="MediumVioletRed" Opacity="0"></SolidColorBrush> hopefully it will change the foreground color when item gets selected

Comment: Still not working. I'm an iOS dev, I just started an App for Windows 8 and I still wonder how Microsoft can sucks so much on this.. It's a simple thing, I shouldn't have to do complicated things! Xcode and Cocoa are so much better.

Answer (score -1):

Add below mentioned code in your StandardStyles.xaml file and change the color you want:

```
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush" Color="Red" />
```